# Symfony allow access for anonymous users and logged in users

Tags: symfony, routes, access-control

I have a route with a response in json to make accessible for logged in users but also anonymous users but in this case with a response with a status code 401.

I tried to add a firewall;

```
route_name:
    pattern: ^/path
    anonymous: true
```

but with this configuration, i get always an anonymous user (in profiler), even if user is logged in.

I tried also adding configuration in access_control instead;

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/path, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

but i keep getting the login form instead.

Any idea how to handle this case? Thanks